# Prime nuber in jquery logic

Tags: jquery

i want to create a page with html and jquery for checking prime number  without  pluginn my need when i clicked on button it check for prime no 
if entered data character any other except number show error message

i written this code but not getting result help me

```html
<!Doctype Html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>
  Jquery Tasks
 </title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
      // storing number in variable
         var number= parseInt($("#txtnum").val());
          $("#txtnum").keypress(function (e) {

          if (e.which >= 48 || e.which <= 57) 
           {
             
           };
          else
            {
               $("#error").html("Please enter only number number").show().fadeOut("slow"); 
               return false;
            }
      });
     $("#check").click(function()
     {
        for (var i = 1; i < number; i++)
              {
               if (number%i==0)
                {
                    res++;
                };
              };
         
             if (res==2)
              {
               $("#error").html("Entered number is a prime number").show().fadeOut("slow");
              };
             else
              {
                $("#error").html("Entered number is not a prime number").show().fadeOut("slow");
                return false;
              };
     });

  </script>
</head>
<body>
 <table align="center">
  
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <h2>Prime number checking</h2>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    Enter Any Number
   </td>
   <td>
    <input type="text" id="txtnum">
   </td>
   <td>
    <span id="error"> </span>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
       <input type="submit" value="Check" id="check">
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of mistakes in your code

- You dont need semicolon after if - else
- var number must be in inside the submit event handler
- res is used but not initialised
- some brackets are not closed
- in checking of proper keys the condition should be (e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57) not ||
- in checking for prime number you only need to check till n/2
- you can break the checking when any number%i condition matches

Keep practicing more :)

```js
$("#txtnum").keypress(function(e) {

  if (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) {
    $("#error").html("Please enter only number number");
    return false;
  }
});
$("#check").click(function() {
  var number = parseInt($("#txtnum").val());
  var res = 0;
  for (var i = 2; i <= number / 2; i++) {
    if (number % i == 0) {
      res++;
      break;
    }
  }
  
  if (res == 0) {
    $("#error").html("Entered number is a prime number");
  } else {
    $("#error").html("Entered number is not a prime number");
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<!Doctype Html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Jquery Tasks
  </title>
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <table align="center">

    <tr>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <h2>Prime number checking</h2>
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Enter Any Number
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="txtnum">
      </td>
      <td>
        <span id="error"> </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="submit" value="Check" id="check">
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you logic is correct but you had a lot of syntax error.

first `if {} else{}` not need semicolon. 
second you some of your brackets and parenthesizes not closed. 
third you used res but not defined or initialized it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
       var res = 0;
        // storing number in variable
        var number = parseInt($("#txtnum").val());
        $("#txtnum").keypress(function(e) {

          if (e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57) {
                
          }
          else {
            $("#error").html("Please enter only number number").show().fadeOut("slow");
            return false;
          }
        });
        $("#check").click(function() {
             res = 0;
             var number = parseInt($("#txtnum").val());
        
          for (var i = 1; i < number; i++) {
            if (number % i == 0) {
              res++;
            }
          };
             console.log(res);
          if (res >= 2) {
            $("#error").html("Entered number is not a prime number").show().fadeOut(3000);
            return false;
          }
          else {
            $("#error").html("Entered number is a prime number").show().fadeOut(3000);
          };
        });
       });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table align="center">
  
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <h2>Prime number checking</h2>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    Enter Any Number
   </td>
   <td>
    <input type="text" id="txtnum">
   </td>
   <td>
    <span id="error"> </span>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
       <input type="submit" value="Check" id="check">
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: it not avoiding characters or others

Comment: sorry for "you logic is correct but" both logic and programming skill is bad :), i think the best way is to take math and programming course :D